# Why is "Boxer Ice" beer now called "BXR Ice"?

Tags: breweries, craft-beers

I just noticed that the logo on one of Minhas Breweries (Calgary Alberta and Monroe Wisconsin) products has changed.  "Boxer Ice" beer now says "BXR Ice", but otherwise looks identical.
Many of their products use the "Boxer" name, so changing only one of them seems unusual.

What is the reason for this subtle name change?

Comment: Why do marketing people do anything? If I had to guess, it was to appeal to younger consumers.

Comment: Because The world wide corporate overlords  are successfully dumming down the populace, BXR has much fewer letters to confuse you.  OMG, LOL Ask your doctor if this television commercial medical advise is right for his wallet.